# Sass sprites not working in deep nested folder

Tags: sass, css-sprites, compass

I'm using SASS sprites: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/

'channel' is the folder name in 'images' that contains my images to be sprited. The following does create an image sprite:

@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "channel/*.png";
@include all-channel-sprites;

However the image path in the CSS is slightly wrong. Its output is this:

```
background-image: url('/images/channel-s78ec12c377.png')
```

But I actually need this:

```
background-image: url('../images/channel-s78ec12c377.png')
```

I've tried changing my import to this but it throws an error:

```
@import "../channel/*.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was to do with the config.rb file. It needed this line:

relative_assets = true